# Exception during the generation Rss by XDocument

Tags: c#, asp.net, rss, linq-to-xml

I'm using XDocument to create a RSS same below code:

```
            var rss = new XDocument(
            new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null),
            new XElement("rss", new XElement("channel",
                                        new XElement("title", blog.Title),
                                        new XElement("link", link),
                                        new XElement("description", blog.Description),
                                        new XElement("generator", "RSS Generated by x"),
                                        new XElement("language", "fa"),
                                        from item in items
                                        select new XElement("item",
                                                            new XElement("title", item.Title),
                                                            new XElement("link", item.Link),
                                                            new XElement("pubDate", item.PubDate),
                                                            new XElement("author", item.Author),
                                                            new XElement("guid", item.Guid),
                                                            new XElement("description", item.Description),
                                                            new XElement("comments", item.Comments)
                                            )
                                ),
                            new XAttribute("version", "2.0")));
```

with some contents an exception occurring during the execution of this code.

```
'.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character.
'', hexadecimal value 0x1D, is an invalid character.
'', hexadecimal value 0x0B, is an invalid character.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should sanitize xml data 
here is what characters can be used inside http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valid_characters_in_XML
valid characters will be

```
public string sanitizeText(string sanitize){
    StringBuilder result = new  StringBuilder();
    foreach(   char x in sanitize){
        if ((x == 0x9 || x == 0xA || x == 0xD) ||   
        ((x >= 0x20) && (x <= 0xD7FF)) ||   
        ((x >= 0xE000) && (x <= 0xFFFD)) ||   
        ((x >= 0x10000) && (x <= 0x10FFFF)))  result.Append(x);
    } 
    return result.ToString();
}
```